# eclipse maven doesn't update the build path

Tags: java, eclipse, maven

I have been hitting my head in rocks because of the maven for two days.

I have forked this github reposotory https://github.com/WilliamKinaan/californium and I am trying to add it to my eclipse.

my problem is that the mvn doesn't update the dependencies. I tried almost everything question on Google.

i did mvn clean
mvn eclipse eclipse
mvn clean install
mvn install

plus i installed m2e plugin.

then from inside eclipse i did maven update (and force update).

in addition, i checked the log of maven, there were some paths such as `main/resources` and `test/resources` does exist, i added them.

and yet eclipse doesn't update my build path.

I am working on mac os

kindly help

Comment: I cloned this repository, ran mvn eclipse:eclipse, imported it to eclipse and it worked fine

Comment: @Bennyz i am so new to maven, and I **hate it**. Anyway, did you run mvn eclipse:eclipse after cloning it directly? how did you import it to your eclipse? What i did is closing the repository, then from eclipse file/create java project and i set the source to the *cloned project* then i started hitting the whole with all these statments. nevertheless i started by mvn eclipse:eclipse and still i have too many dependencies that haven't been added yet.

Comment: I dislike maven myself, I use Gradle myself (which can be used with maven projects as well),

I ran it immediately after cloning. Then I imported it to eclipse, using right-click in Project Explorer window -> Import existing projects into workspace

Comment: What error does maven give when you do the mvn clean install?

Comment: Tell us what version of Eclipse and Maven are you using. I am using Eclipse Kepler plus Maven 3.1.1 and M2 1.4.0, and dependencies are updated fine.

Comment: @LittleSanti eclipse: `Luna Service Release 2 (4.4.2)` maven `apache-maven-3.3.3` , m2e - Maven Integration for Eclipse (includes Incubating components) 1.6.1.20150625-2338 and   m2e connector for build-helper-maven-plugin 0.15.0.201207090124

Answer (score 0):

Try [maven command line](https://maven.apache.org/download.cgi) to run (be in your project path)

```
mvn eclipse:eclipse
```

The command with option parameter [here](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-eclipse-plugin/eclipse-mojo.html), if your project is WEB project, command will like

```
mvn eclipse:eclipse -Dwtpversion=2.0
```

Hope this can help you.